# Stored Procedure sql data insert error

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, ado.net

```
     private void btnInsert_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
     {     
       empCode = txtCode.Text;
       empName = txtName.Text;
       empCell = txtCell.Text;
       empAddress = txtAddress.Text;
        try
        {
            using (cmd = new SqlCommand(" empInsert ", conn))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@empcode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = empCode;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@empname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = empName;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@empcell", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = empCell;
                cmd.Parameters.Add("@empaddress", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = empAddress;
                conn.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            MessageBox.Show("succesfully inserted", "Congrates");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("can't Insert there is error :" + ex, "Error");
        }

        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }
    }
```

Here is Stored procedure on `SQL` DB side.

```
use GDK
GO
create PROCEDURE dbo.empInsert

@id     as    VARCHAR(10,
@name as VARCHAR(10),
@cell as  VARCHAR(10),
@address     as   VARCHAR(20) 

AS

BEGIN

INSERT INTO EmployeeRecord(empcode,empname,empcell,empaddress) VALUES( @id, @name,  @cell, @address)   
END
```

I am unable to `INSERT`  in DB.

Kindly help in this regard

Comment: The parameter names in the application code must match those of the underlying stored procedure in the database that you are calling.

Answer (score 1):

You have parameter name `@id` in stored procedure but you are passing `@empcode`

*Change*

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@empcode", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = empCode;
```

*To*

```
cmd.Parameters.Add("@id", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = empCode;
```

Comment: Actually none of them match.  @id is just one example.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your parameter names do not match.

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> When using parameters with a SqlCommand to execute a SQL Server stored
>   procedure, the names of the parameters added to the Parameters
>   collection must match the names of the parameter markers in the stored
>   procedure.

So this is what you need:

```
cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", empCode);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@name", empName);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cell", empCell);
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@address", empAddress);
```

Comment: Thanks....the problem was here... using (cmd = new SqlCommand(" empInsert ", conn))......it was .... using (cmd = new SqlCommand(" dbo.empInsert ", conn))

Comment: I would check to see if it is successful when you trim the leading and trailing whitespace off the stored procedure name. That might be the problem as well, try it like this: `new SqlCommand("empInsert", conn))`.